# How to change language syntax highlighting without affecting run option?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I use the .pyde filetype to make processing.py code, it's jpython so basically it's typed the same as Python however needs a different command to run than python. However every time I set the language mode to Python it changes the command to run, any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so apparently there's, like, defaults that it adds or something, so even commenting out python in the executor map [which has higher priority than extension map] doesn't help, you literally need to have `"python": null` in there [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmk1J.png)